# How to get json data to an angular array variable

Tags: php, json, angular

I am trying to get a json result to an array object .I am echoing a json data in php. like this.

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
$arr=  '[{
   "id": "1",
   "date": "2020-03-21",
   "status": "present",
   "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
   "id": "2",
   "date": "2020-03-24",
   "status": "present",
   "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
   "id": "3",
   "date": "2020-03-25",
   "status": "absent",
   "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
   "id": "4",
   "date": "2020-03-26",
   "status": "absent",
   "studentid": "1"
  }
 ]';

echo $arr;
?>
```

~

---

How to get absentees using angular in an array.

Angular part i tried didnt work

```
      this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=getattendance", JSON.stringify(this.postData),options)


          .subscribe( (data) => {
          this.setUsersArray(data);
          console.log(data + "URL DATA"+JSON.stringify(this.postData));

           }


      );

=====================================================================
    setUsersArray(data){

       if (data instanceof Array) {
                       {

                        this.date_present = data.map(function (ele) {
                        if(ele.status==='present')
                        {

                          return ele.date;

                        }



                        });
                        this.date_absent = data.map(function (ele) {
                          if(ele.status==='absent')


                          return ele.date;

                          });
                   }
                    }
```

I am getting date_absent and date_present as null.Why am i getting this as null.Please help me. I am new to angular.

Comment: Looks like your if block is outside of the subscribe? So you probably don't have access to data.

Comment: actuaally that part is inside a function setUsersArray(data);

Comment: @sam sorry for that mistake.I have corrected it

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to use map for this, as map will return something for each item in the array you are looping over. So for `this.date_present ` i would expect your data to look like ["2020-03-21", "2020-03-24", undefined, undefined]; You could use forEach instead to avoid this and push the values to the array `this.date_present `. Also your array looks like a string which is probably why you cannot use it at the moment, try throwing a debugger inside the if block and see if it is called.

Answer (score 1):

try for loop in typescript

```
setUsersArray(data:any){
for(let item of data){
  console.log(item);
  if(item.status==='present') {
    this.present.push(item.date);
  }
  if(item.status==='absent') {
    this.absent.push(item.date);
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to this url 
$characters = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed and make an associative array
https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/